# pushfrontviewcontroler open blank screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swrevealviewcontroller

I need to set to root for second view controller through `SWRevealViewController`. But when I call `pushFrontViewcontroler` it become a blank screen. All my label that I defined in storyboard is missing. But the external xib i include is properly display. Am I missing something? Please enlighten me on how to solve this. Below is the code i use to call the second view controller.

SWRevealViewController *revealController = self.revealViewController;

```
ImageDetailViewController *imageViewController = [[ImageDetailViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:imageViewController];

[revealController pushFrontViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

I also try using this but still failed

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:imageViewController];

[self.revealViewController setFrontViewController:navigationController];
[self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
```

[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WScBd.png)

Comment: Why you don´t put your root view controller on StoryBoard?

Comment: i already put a root view controller on storyboard. You can view screenshot of my application.

Comment: can you post an image with your historyboard?

Comment: I updated my question and just notice when i create outlet manually it showing in my second view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is the instantiation of your imageViewController

```
ImageDetailViewController *imageViewController = [[ImageDetailViewController alloc] init];
```

if you do something like this

```
ImageDetailViewController *imageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyImageViewController"];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:imageViewController];
[revealController pushFrontViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

this works perfect, but I still recommends you have your navViewControllers on your storyboard and change them like this code

```
     - (void) goMainViewControllerAction
    {
    UINavigationController* navigationController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@“MainNavViewController”];
    [self.revealViewController pushFrontViewController:navigationController   animated:YES];
     }
  //

- (void) goImageViewControllerAction
    {
       UINavigationController* navigationController = [self.storyboard    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyImageNavViewController"];
       [self.revealViewController     pushFrontViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
    }
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: your solution help me a lot. i can solve my problem now. Thank you for the help and clarification. Have a good day mate.

Comment: @Acan1234 remember vote and accept if the answer is what you need this is the way to say thanks on StackOverFlows